# A simultaneous equation question

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$38$ bottles of soda was consumed by $18$ women. Some took $2$ and others took $3$ .
(A) How many women took $2$ sodas?
(B) How many women took $3$ sodas?

I thought I might use simultaneous equations though I dont know how to come up with it . Or maybe I should use quadratic? I dont really know which I should use and how I should use it. Please help and show the working step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for alternate solution: If all of the women took two bottles, how many bottles would've been taken? How many women need to take one more bottle if $38$ bottles have been taken all in all?

---

Simultaneous equations: Let $x$ be the number of women who took two bottles, and $y$ the number of women who took $3$. Then we have
$$
\cases{x + y = 18\\
2x + 3y = 38}
$$
where the first line says that there are $18$ women in total, and the second line says that $38$ bottles have been taken.

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of women who took two bottles be labelled $w_{2}$, similarly for the women who took three bottles, call them $w_{3}$.

Then it is clear that $w_{2}+w_{3}=18$.

The other relation is that the total bottles of soda (being $38$) must equal $2w_{2}+3w_{3}$. Hence your simultaneous system looks like
\begin{eqnarray}
w_{2}+w_{3} &=& 18 \\
2w_{2}+3w_{3} &=& 38
\end{eqnarray}
Multiplying the top relation by $2$ yeilds
\begin{equation}
2w_{2}+2w_{3}=36
\end{equation}
Subtrating this from the lower relation gives
\begin{equation}
2w_{2}+3w_{3}-2w_{2}-2w_{3} = 38-36
\end{equation}
Or
$$w_{3}=2$$
Which means that there were two women who took three bottles, meaning sixteen women took two bottles. We can verify this by inserting the above value for $w_{3}$ into the first relation at the outset,
\begin{equation}
w_{2}+2=18
\end{equation}